# Certain faces not showing after Model Export to .OBJ from Blender

Tags: blender, modeling, 3d-modelling

So here's a pistol that I've been working on for quiet some time now using Blender 2.79b.
It is the first model I've ever worked on and it has been shaping up surprisingly well. The problem that has recently popped up though is the fact that when I try to export the model below as an .OBJ file, multiple faces are excluded and end up looking from this:

[Blender Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M7aI.png)

To this:

[OBJ Model in Unity Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqJAh.png)

A you can see, multiple faces are suddenly gone and some graphical glitches are present. I'm not really sure if the fact that I applied a Boolean Difference Modifier at most of these meshes has something to do with this issue, but anyways I would appreciate it extremely if you could help me resolve this issue :)

Comment: Hi DrSandvich. I think you had better ask this question on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay, I'll do so immediately.